# Explain why the initial-value problem $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{y}$ , $y(x_0) = y_0$ has no solution for $y_0 = 0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Can you guys help me with this?

> Without solving, explain why the initial-value problem $\frac{dy}{dx} = \sqrt{y}$ , $y(x_0) = y_0$ has no solution for $y_0 = 0$.

I tried to proved it by saying that $y$ can't be zero because it 
will be in the Denominator, but I think it isn't 100% correct.

Comment: what's wrong with $y(x)=\frac{x^2}{4}$ and $y(0)=0?$

Comment: It's gonna be equal to zero, the y(0) .. there is no constant it's a particular solution.

Comment: I can't see your point. The question you are asking is why are there no solutions when $y_0=0$. There is clearly a solution, doesn't matter whether it's the general one or just a particular

Comment: Furthermore, you get $y^{-1/2}dy=dx \implies 2\sqrt{y}=x+c \implies y=(x+c)^2/4$

Comment: Yeah I know that it has a solution but my professor asking that if y_0=0 then there is no solution, I tried to figure out why by using several ideas from me and me classmates we can't know why there is no solution

Comment: But I think that x_0 can be any number in R but y_0 is zero

Comment: Obviously you get a solution by looking at the example $y(x)=x^2/4$...

Comment: But the question said that is has no solution at all at y_0=0

Comment: @nood $y=0$ is a solution satisfying $y_0=0$. !!!

Comment: Can you please explain it

Comment: Either you or your professor is confused. Suppose $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ and if either $f$ or $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ fails to be continuous in a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$ then **there is no guarantee** that there is a **unique** solution to the initial value problem at $(x_0,y_0)$. It could be that there is no solution, more than one linearly independent solutions, or only one solution.

Comment: What is the required  domain of the function $y$? If $y=x^2/4$ then $y'=\sqrt y $ only for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Excellent point, there is no solution on an open interval containing $x_0=0$ although there is one on an interval $[0,\epsilon)$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: $y(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbf{R}$ works fine...

Comment: Where is your confusion?   A upward looking parabola of unit focal length has its vertex sliding on x-axis by an amount $c$ in $ \pm 2 \sqrt y -x = c $

Comment: @HansLundmark You are correct.

Answer (score 2):

Just to summarize:

$y=0$ is a solution.

If $c\ge0$ then

$$ y=\begin{cases}\dfrac{(x-c)^2}{4}&\text{ for }x\ge c\\0&\text{ for }x<c\end{cases} $$

is also a solution.

So the problem should not have been stated that there was **no** solution, rather that there was no **unique** solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ means that the function that solves the ODE will be a function of $x$, i.e. of the form $y(x).$

As other comments have pointed out, there is indeed one solution. There is a theorem in ODEs, the Picard-Lindelof theorem which tells you when a solution to an ODE exists and is unique. The function that solves the ODE has to be *Lipschitz* continuous.

This is defined by $\exists M>0$ s.t. $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|, \forall x,y$. 
Write our ODE as $y'=y^{1/2}$ which means the solution is $y(x)=2y^{3/2}$, this function is not Lipschitz and so it is not a unique solution to the ODE. Clearly $y(0)=0$ is a solution.

Sometimes, it is easy to come up with other solutions to the ODE, but not always.

**Extra info:**

There is no analogous theorem for PDEs. We cannot tell, in general, whether the solution to a PDE exists or is unique in an arbitrary domain, especially for non-linear ones like Navier-Stokes.